# Android Pick Video files From Gallery not Working in Nexus 5

Tags: android, android-intent, video, gallery

In my application i need to send images and videos from gallery to server, i had used following code for picking images and videos from galery. It works fine in the devices which are not in lollipop version.

```
Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK); 
photoPickerIntent.setType("image/* video/*");
startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent,REQUEST_CODE_GALLERY_FILES);
```

And in the onActivityresult,

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent returnedIntent) {
     super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, returnedIntent);
     if (returnedIntent == null) return;
     switch (requestCode) {
         case REQUEST_CODE_GALLERY_FILES:
             Uri uri = returnedIntent.getData();               
             break;
     }
}
```

But in Nexus 5 like devices it shows only images, videos are not showed in the list. As there is Gallery is not available in Lollipop.
    How can i get video file also form gallery or from anywhere for lollipop devices.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this method.

```
private void pickImageOrVideo() {
      if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 19) {
            Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK); 
            photoPickerIntent.setType("image/* video/*");
            startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent,REQUEST_CODE_GALLERY_FILES);
       } else {
            Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            photoPickerIntent.setType("*/*");
            startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, REQUEST_CODE_GALLERY_FILES);
       }
}
```

for both image and video you can use `setType(*/*);` if device is running on lollipop.

here `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` is give only gallery selection while `ACTION_PICK` give many more options to pick image and video from different action,

I hope it helps!

Comment: i had tried your code but it displays images only in the picker UI. Videos are not showing there....

Comment: try this instead of above answer. Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
intent.setType("image/* video/*");

Comment: no its not working in lollipop version it opens Photo application and only images are displayed

Answer (score 3):

Add `intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_MIME_TYPES, new String[] {"image/*", "video/*"});` to the SDK20+ launching, along with main type.

Comment: Thanks for this -- tough to find this answer for some reason, perhaps because it's only on latest versions.

Comment: tbh guys, we switched back to two selection buttons, got like something like nokia or so and were just tired of this misbehaviour